# API request returned- Airflow 404 = lots of circles

Tags: airflow

I have Airflow,

tried to create API Request for example GET version

```
http://server01:8081/admin/rest_api/api?api=rest_api_plugin_version
```

after executed returned Airflow 404 = lots of circles

How solve this problem?

Comment: I assume you’ve followed all the [steps](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to install the REST API Plugin? Don’t forget to restart the Airflow webserver.

Comment: what is your `web_server_port ` in airflow.cfg file?. Can you try with `8080` port: `http://server01:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=rest_api_plugin_version`

Comment: I believe if you see the Airflow's custom 404 page (the circles), then you're probably hitting the correct port already.

Comment: I'm sure the port is right too. BUT I can't understand why the circles are returning...

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko I know I'm asking you to think back a long way but did you ever get past this problem? I haven't hit it myself (yet) but I'm keen to know if there are issues with https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin before I spend any time investigating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does works for me, I'm using airflow 1.10 version. 
Please find below screenshot for the same, Let me know if anyone faces any issue with this.

[image: Cloudera : Airflow]

Answer (score 2):

This rest plugin ( https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin ) seems to be not supported by airflow 1.8.1 (or after) .Please use 1.8.0 (or before) ,to install airflow 1.8 which works with the above REST API plugin use install command  unlike  which installs 1.8.1 onwards.